# Use AMPscript to create dynamic math calculation of a reduction price

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-studio, dynamiccomponent

How could I write AMPScript for this basic calculation below?

I would like to calculate the price after the reduction 
Example:
Price = 65000
Reduction = 30%
Reduction Price = 65000 -((65000*30)/100)

Moreover I would like to set the reduction price during only a period of time for example 1 month.

After this period, the reduction is no longer available. I want the reduction rate to disappear from the display of the co,ntent of my email, after the duration is complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello Pauline and welcome to SFSE!

To answer the first part, this is how you would do the math:

```
%%[
   /* I have these hard coded, but replace the 65000 and "0.30" with your attributes */
   set @price = 65000
   set @reduction = 30

   /* 
   ----- Sample of values with Sendable DE attributes -----
   set @price = AttributeValue("Price")
   set @reduction = AttributeValue("Reduction")

   ----- Assuming that Price and Reduction are the field names in your sendable DE -----
   */


   set @total = Subtract(@price, Divide(Multiply(@price,@reduction), 100))
]%%

<p>Your price is now: %%=v(@total)=%% after your %%=v(@reduction)=%% percent discount!</p>
```

Using `%%=v(@total)=%%` inside your HTML will output the variable `@total` using the [%%=v()=%%](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/v.htm) function, which displays the value of the AMPScript variable you set previously in your code.

For example, the above code would output:

`Your price is now: 65000 after your 30 percent discount!`

As you mentioned you are a complete beginner in AMPscript, I would recommend using the following resources to increase you knowledge and capabilities:

1. [**SFMC AMPscript documentation and syntax guide**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/syntaxGuide.htm)
2. @AdamSpriggs and @EliotHarper AMPscript book - [**AMPscript Guide**](https://ampscript.guide/)

Please note that if you have your price and/or reduction stored as anything but integers, you will need to use the [FormatNumber()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/FormatNumber.htm) function to correctly format them.

As to your second part,  this is not possible inside of AMPscript as it only runs sever-side (when compiling the email, prior to send).

Your only choice really is to create a dynamic image to display the price. This will let you update it accordingly - or use a 3rd party service (Movable Ink, LiveClicker, etc) to do this for you.

Once an email is completed on the server and sent, the contents and direct code of it cannot be changed. This is for security purposes.

You can change linked CSS files (Link tag) and images (src) though. Fancy CSS replaces and appends only work on SOME email clients, so for something as important as a displayed price, I would not recommend this as an option. Which is why unfortunately, an image is your only real choice.

To get around this (as having an item as important as price held in a potentially blocked  image and the highly increased LOE to create these images) Most people will put a disclaimer next to the price and list available dates in legal text at the bottom and explain it will return to original price ($65,000) after time period - usually stating a specific date.

Comment: Many thanks @Gortonington, for you help ! I just copied and past your AMPscript and it doesn't work. I can send the email, I have no errors but it's not displayed on the content of my email. :(

Comment: DId you output the vars like so: `Your Discounted Price: %%=v(@total)=%%` or `Original Price: %%=v(@price)=%%`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand I begin in AMPScript.... Could you explain me please the  diffrence between "v" and "var"? I would like to Concat the Price before the reduction, the sales Price and syntax comments. Then, Do I have to copy paste the code in the Text content or in the HTML Editor with the help of the AMPScript Formatting?

Comment: @Pauline - I have added in more details into my answer to assist with your comment above. I, as well, added a couple good resources for learning AMPscript.

Comment: @Pauline - not sure what your previous comment was asking.

Comment: I would like to know if I can replace the 65000 by the "Attribute Name" of the Data extension, in the code ? In order to display the different price per susbscriber within the data extension, for personalization. Does it make sense ?

Comment: added in a commented example of how to set the vars based off Sendable DE/ List attributes instead of a hardcoded value.

Comment: @Pauline - if this answers your question, please be sure to click the checkmark next to the answer to mark it as correct to allow for others with this issue to easily find the solution.